# Debian server on a Intel Core i3 and Intel Q57 Chipset - will it work?

Tags: linux, debian

I want to build a Debian server (running samba, postfix, apache - without X11) on a Intel Core i3 / Intel Q57 Chipset system. I'm relativly new to the Linux-World but had driver issues already within my desktop (ATI GPU) that I wasn't able to solve.

Will the following components work fine with Debian Linux?

- Intel Core i3-530 2x2.93GHz 4MB VideoHD Sock1156 (Clarkdale) BOX
- Gigabyte GA-Q57M-S2H GL/SATA/R/DVI/HDMI/DP Q57 HD Graphics mATX Sock1156
- Raid: Samsung SpinPoint F3 HD502HJ - 500GB 7200rpm 16MB 3.5zoll SATA300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Debian GNU/Linux device driver check page](http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/) tells you what hardware on your system is supported by the kernel, and by which versions.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say whether it works without actually testing it. I'd grab the [Live CD](http://live.debian.net/) matching the version of Debian you want to run and test it. Debian emphasizes stability and therefore it's releases normally lags behind when it comes to kernel versions and other applications. That means they might not work while more up-to-date distributions like e.g. Ubuntu 10.4 LTS server edition (or unreleased Debian versions, like Sid) may work better.